# No package available python-setuptools on centos 5.8

Tags: linux, centos, python

I am running oracle-linux (same as rhel) 5.8 and am trying to create a localized version of python including pip and a few modules.  I have downloaded pip but am unable to install it:

```
[root@oracle-linux Python-2.7.5]# yum -y install python-setuptools python-pip
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with ULN.
ULN support will be disabled.
epel                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package python-setuptools available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-pip.noarch 0:0.8-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: python-setuptools for package: python-pip
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
python-pip-0.8-1.el5.noarch from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: python-setuptools is needed by package python-pip-0.8-1.el5.noarch (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: python-setuptools is needed by package python-pip-0.8-1.el5.noarch (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So let us try to install the dependency:

```
[root@oracle-linux Python-2.7.5]# yum install -y python-setuptools
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with ULN.
ULN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package python-setuptools available.
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-setuptools` is in the base repo. Buy a contract so that you have access to it.